# How to fix an external monitor showing only half of the screen?

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors

My laptop's screen is broken. I've been using an external monitor for a month without any problems (Windows 10 and Elementary OS). Today I decided to switch to Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit. When I boot using a USB key the monitor only displays half of the screen as you can see in the photo and the mouse cursor can slip to the left side.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Go to System Settings/Displays and check the `mirror displays` option, then click the APPLY button. You **may** need to change the resolution to get the desktop size you desire.